# iPhone app calendar starting at sunset how too

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am trying to make a calendar app for iPhone that the new day will start at sunset. as sunset changes i would have to get longitude and latitude and use this to find the time of sunset and then set it to refresh as the next day. would this be the best way?